# Java Slick2D how to draw text with a centered alingment

Tags: java, slick

I've made a button class that can be drawn and clicked on. How can I write the text of that button (using the slick drawing API, g.drawString()) with a Centered alingment (so that the text is exactly centered in a rect with defined x,y,widht and height).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly you want to create a class that writes text on a button for you centered to a rect.

```
public class DrawCentered(){
    public DrawCentered(String chars, Rect r){
        TrueTypeFont font = new TrueTypeFont(new Font(...));
        int width = font.getWidth(chars);
        int height = font.getHeight(chars);

        g.drawString((r.x + r.width / 2) - (width / 2), 
                     (r.y + r.height / 2) - (height / 2), 
                     chars);
    }
}
```

Note **Above code is untested**

I hope this helps, and if you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask. 

JavaDocs such as:

 [Slick2D TrueTypeFont JavaDoc](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.html#drawString(float,%20float,%20java.lang.String)) 

[JavaAwtFont JavaDoc](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/javaawtFont.htm)
are great tools to help you when you are stuck.

Cheers!